# Mapping existing data to match data structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a redux state `clubDetails` that comes back from an API response. I basically need to map it to match the object of the structured data from below. For each `operationalHours` day it needs to be part of the object `openingHoursSpecification` and in the array. So for each day's hours it needs to follow the structured data format like below. From what I know each day can have its own individual hours or it can be `monToFriHrs`. There's also departments that each have their own hours that will also need to be mapped to follow the same structured data. The `clubDetails` is an object for example like this.

Since the hours for the days can be individual days I was thinking maybe having an array to match the days? If it's for `monToFriHrs` it has to match the structured data where it creates an array and has each day in the array.

```
const days = [mondayHrs, tuesdayHrs, wednesdayHrs,thursdayHrs,fridayHrs, monToFriHrs, saturdayHrs, sundayHrs]
```

What would be the best way to tackle this? I am using a function and tried `clubDetails.map` but I got stuck due to the `operationalHours` and the `departments` since it gets kind of complicated.

```
clubDetails = {
  ...,
  name: "Bob's Store",
  address: {
   address1: "123 fake st,
   city: "Fake york",
   country: "USA,
   postalCode: 11111,
   state: "CA"
  },
  operationalHours: {
    saturdayHrs: {
      startHrs: '09:00',
      endHrs: '20:00'
    },
    sundayHrs: {
      startHrs: '10:00',
      endHrs: '18:00'
    },
    monToFriHrs: {
      startHrs: '10:00',
      endHrs: '20:00'
    }
  }
  services: [
    {
      displayName: 'Pharmacy',
      name: 'PHARMACY',
      operationalHours: {
        saturdayHrs: {
          startHrs: '09:00',
          endHrs: '17:00'
        },
        sundayHrs: {
          startHrs: '00:00',
          endHrs: '00:00',
          isClosed: true
        },
        monToFriHrs: {
          startHrs: '09:00',
          endHrs: '19:00'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      displayName: 'Cafe',
      name: 'CAFE',
      operationalHours: {
        saturdayHrs: {
          startHrs: '10:00',
          endHrs: '19:00'
        },
        sundayHrs: {
          startHrs: '10:00',
          endHrs: '18:00'
        },
        monToFriHrs: {
          startHrs: '10:00',
          endHrs: '19:00'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

Example of structured data.

```
{
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Store",
      "name": "Dave's Department Store",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "1600 Saratoga Ave",
        "addressLocality": "San Jose",
        "addressRegion": "CA",
        "postalCode": "95129",
        "addressCountry": "US"
      },
      "geo": {
        "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
        "latitude": 37.293058,
        "longitude": -121.988331
      },
      "url": "http://www.example.com/store-locator/sl/San-Jose-Westgate-Store/1427",
      "priceRange": "$$$",
      "telephone": "+14088717984",
      "openingHoursSpecification": [
        {
          "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
          "dayOfWeek": [
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday"
          ],
          "opens": "08:00",
          "closes": "23:59"
        },
        {
          "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
          "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
          "opens": "08:00",
          "closes": "23:00"
        }
      ],
      "department": [
        {
          "@type": "Pharmacy",
          "name": "Dave's Pharmacy",
          "telephone": "+14088719385",
          "openingHoursSpecification": [
            {
              "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
              "dayOfWeek": [
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday"
              ],
              "opens": "09:00",
              "closes": "19:00"
            },
            {
              "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
              "dayOfWeek": "Saturday",
              "opens": "09:00",
              "closes": "17:00"
            },
            {
              "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
              "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
              "opens": "11:00",
              "closes": "17:00"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

This is what the expected should look like after mapping `clubDetails` to the structured data JSON.

```
{
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Store",
      "name": "Bob's Store",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "123 fake st",
        "addressLocality": "Fake york",
        "addressRegion": "CA",
        "postalCode": "11111",
        "addressCountry": "USA"
      },
      "geo": {
        "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
        "latitude": 37.293058,
        "longitude": -121.988331
      },
      "url": "http://www.example.com/store-locator/sl/San-Jose-Westgate-Store/1427",
      "priceRange": "$$$",
      "telephone": "+14088717984",
      "openingHoursSpecification": [
        {
          "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
          "dayOfWeek": [
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday"
          ],
          "opens": "10:00",
          "closes": "20:00"
        },
        {
          "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
          "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
          "opens": "10:00",
          "closes": "18:00"
        },
        {
          "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
          "dayOfWeek": "Saturday",
          "opens": "09:00",
          "closes": "20:00"
        }
      ],
      "department": [
        {
          "@type": "Pharmacy",
          "name": "Pharmacy",
          "telephone": "+14088719385",
          "openingHoursSpecification": [
            {
              "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
              "dayOfWeek": [
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday"
              ],
              "opens": "09:00",
              "closes": "19:00"
            },
            {
              "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
              "dayOfWeek": "Saturday",
              "opens": "09:00",
              "closes": "17:00"
            },
            {
              "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
              "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
              "opens": "00:00",
              "closes": "00:00"
            },
            {
          "@type": "Cafe",
          "name": "Cafe",
          "telephone": "5555555555",
          "openingHoursSpecification": [
            {
              "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
              "dayOfWeek": [
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday"
              ],
              "opens": "10:00",
              "closes": "19:00"
            },
            {
              "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
              "dayOfWeek": "Saturday",
              "opens": "10:00",
              "closes": "19:00"
            },
            {
              "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
              "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
              "opens": "10:00",
              "closes": "18:00"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I decided to go with.

```
const generateStructuredData = (clubDetails, pathname) => {
  let weekDays = [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday"
  ];
  let clubDetailsObj = {};
  clubDetailsObj["@context"] = "https://schema.org";
  clubDetailsObj["@type"] = "Store";
  clubDetailsObj["name"] = clubDetails.name;
  clubDetailsObj["address"] = {};
  clubDetailsObj["address"]["@type"] = "PostalAddress";
  clubDetailsObj["address"]["streetAddress"] = clubDetails.address.address1;
  clubDetailsObj["address"]["addressLocality"] = clubDetails.address.city;
  clubDetailsObj["address"]["addressRegion"] = clubDetails.address.state;
  clubDetailsObj["address"]["postalCode"] = clubDetails.address.postalCode;
  clubDetailsObj["address"]["addressCountry"] = clubDetails.address.addressCountry;


  clubDetailsObj["geo"] = {};
  clubDetailsObj["geo"]["@type"] = "GeoCoordinates";
  clubDetailsObj["geo"]["latitude"] = clubDetails.geoPoint.latitude;
  clubDetailsObj["geo"]["longitude"] = clubDetails.geoPoint.longitude

  clubDetailsObj["url"] = `https://www.test.com${pathname}`;
  clubDetailsObj["telephone"] = "+999999999";

  clubDetailsObj["openingHoursSpecification"] = [];

  formatDeptHours(clubDetailsObj["openingHoursSpecification"], clubDetails, weekDays);

  clubDetailsObj["department"] = [];

  for(let service of clubDetails.services){

    let deptElement = {};
    deptElement["@type"] = service.displayName;
    deptElement["name"] = service.displayName;
    deptElement["telephone"] = "+999999999";

    deptElement["openingHoursSpecification"] = [];

    formatDeptHours(deptElement["openingHoursSpecification"], service, weekDays);

    clubDetailsObj["department"].push(deptElement);
  }

  return clubDetailsObj;
}

const formatDeptHours = (openingHours, service, weekDays) => {
  for(let key in service.operationalHours){
    let hours = {};
    hours["@type"] = "OpeningHoursSpecification";
    if(key === 'monToFriHrs'){
      hours["dayOfWeek"] = weekDays;
      hours["opens"] = service.operationalHours.monToFriHrs.startHrs;
      hours["closes"] = service.operationalHours.monToFriHrs.endHrs;
    }
    else if(key === 'saturdayHrs'){
      hours["@type"] = "OpeningHoursSpecification";
      hours["dayOfWeek"] = "Saturday";
      hours["opens"] = service.operationalHours.saturdayHrs.startHrs;
      hours["closes"] = service.operationalHours.saturdayHrs.endHrs;
    }
    else if(key === 'sundayHrs'){
      hours["@type"] = "OpeningHoursSpecification";
      hours["dayOfWeek"] = "Sunday";
      hours["opens"] = service.operationalHours.sundayHrs.startHrs;
      hours["closes"] = service.operationalHours.sundayHrs.endHrs;
    }
    else if(key === 'mondayHrs'){
      hours["@type"] = "OpeningHoursSpecification";
      hours["dayOfWeek"] = "Monday";
      hours["opens"] = service.operationalHours.mondayHrs.startHrs;
      hours["closes"] = service.operationalHours.mondayHrs.endHrs;
    }
    else if(key === 'tuesdayHrs'){
      hours["@type"] = "OpeningHoursSpecification";
      hours["dayOfWeek"] = "Tuesday";
      hours["opens"] = service.operationalHours.tuesdayHrs.startHrs;
      hours["closes"] = service.operationalHours.tuesdayHrs.endHrs;
    }
    else if(key === 'wednesdayHrs'){
      hours["@type"] = "OpeningHoursSpecification";
      hours["dayOfWeek"] = "Wednesday";
      hours["opens"] = service.operationalHours.wednesdayHrs.startHrs;
      hours["closes"] = service.operationalHours.wednesdayHrs.endHrs;
    }
    else if(key === 'thursdayHrs'){
      hours["@type"] = "OpeningHoursSpecification";
      hours["dayOfWeek"] = "Thursday";
      hours["opens"] = service.operationalHours.thursdayHrs.startHrs;
      hours["closes"] = service.operationalHours.tuesdayHrs.endHrs;
    }
    else if(key === 'fridayHrs'){
      hours["@type"] = "OpeningHoursSpecification";
      hours["dayOfWeek"] = "friday";
      hours["opens"] = service.operationalHours.fridayHrs.startHrs;
      hours["closes"] = service.operationalHours.fridayHrs.endHrs;
    }
    openingHours.push(hours);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to map in a lot of extraneous information like urls and coordinates. I'd suggest going at each mapping systematically and using a full function as opposed to a single map call. Find where each key corresponds to what the output should look like, and do the required processing to convert them.